# Video not showing in Iphone Devices

Tags: css, html

http://flynautwork.com/newfountain/index.php
I have used HTML Video tag on home page for video which is working on all pc and laptops and even on android Devices but nothing is showing on iPhone devices . Need Help !!

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this I think should be work:-

```
<video id="myVideo" loop="" muted="" autoplay="" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="">
  <source src="fl-admin/images/fw-home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```